# Problem faced while querying Using Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am having difficulties getting a subset of results From a huge set of results 
and then performing a join on this particular subset..
can anyone help regarding this??

More specifically,

Say I have an student Table which contains 1000 rows of student
and department table which has the list of departments.
What I want to do is to get a subset of rows say from 510 to 520
and then perform a join on these rows with the department table..

can anyone help me regarding this???

Comment: How is student mapped to departments?

Comment: each student table has a field called department_id which is mapped to the Department_id of the DEPARTMENT TABLE .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using one and only query:

Once you have your criteria object, do this:

```
criteria.SetFirstResult(510).SetMaxResult(10);
```